# Android app ImageView not showing up on my particular device

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm quite a beginner in android programming, so forgive me for any trivialities. I've developed a small app using Android-SDK and Eclipse-ADT that maintains information in an sqlite database. Now here is a simple activity that reads product information using SQLiteDatabase object and updates the editbox controls. But one of the information is an image-location for that product (typically '/mnt/sdcard/something.jpg'). I use an ImageView control to display this image as described in the Android API:

```
img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(c.getString(2)));
```

img is a variable representing the ImageView:

```
img=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgDet);
```

This works well on all android devices and emulators I've tested on, except one - on my particular device (Karbonn A30), the imageview is just blank, it doesn't show up anything!! What do you think could be the issue?

Comment: because it is simply a crappy device? :) Have you tried setting any other Bitmap to the ImageView on that device?

Comment: @MocialovBoris - The default image setting for the imageView which is "@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" shows up fine. Its only when during runtime when I try to set the image using a file that its fails. Also, all other functionality of the app is working well, so I don't think the device is crappy.

Comment: Well all devices are supposed to support both base and progressive jpeg, but it might be worth just trying it out as a png instead, just to narrow down the problem a bit...

Comment: @Sheldon - Switching to PNG made no difference at all. The issue still persists on my device, while it works on all other devices.

Comment: I don't have any specific knowledge here with which I could help you. However, you have made some progress, and I suggest experimenting with different images (sizes and other characteristics) to see if you can narrow down the problem further.